# Magento: Passing value from template file to block

Tags: magento

In my magento module, I need to get the selected value from a select dropdown of a .phtml file and retrieve the value from the corresponding block class so that I can do a database query acc. to the value recieved. Pls help me with this.

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve the dropdown value in the phtml file with pure javascript or with methods of the javascript framework "prototype" which is used by magento.

Afterwards , call your block method which does the database query directly from the phtml file and pass the dropdown value as a parameter to the block method.

Lets assume your block method is getValueFromDatabase($param), then you can access your block method from within the phtml file with $this->getValueFromDatabase($param).

You have access to all block methods from the phtml file.

Comment: If we get the selected value as var store = jQuery('#shipping_pickup_store').val(); Then how can we sent the var to the block method coz it takes parameters in the form $param.